# why can't i get my call recording app to work?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement an app that allows me to record the audio of calls, activating the service via a toggle button. I can't figure out what is wrong with my code as once I set the toggle button to ON and initiate the call, there is no file saved.
I don't understand if the problem is in saving (maybe I'm looking for the file in the wrong directory?), Or in the fact that it doesn't actually record.
I'm using AndroidStudio 4.0 and i'm trying my app on my Samsung S9.

Thanks in andvance for helping !

RecordService.java

```
package com.example.registrachiamate;

import android.app.MediaRouteButton;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

public class RecordService extends Service {
    private MediaRecorder rec;
    private File file;
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        file= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        Date date=new Date();
        CharSequence sdf= DateFormat.format("MM-dd-yy-hh-mm--ss",date.getTime());
        rec=new MediaRecorder();
        rec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        rec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        rec.setOutputFile(file.getAbsolutePath()+"/"+sdf+"rec.3gp");
        rec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);

        TelephonyManager manager=(TelephonyManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        assert manager != null;
        manager.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String phoneNumber) {
                //super.onCallStateChanged(state, phoneNumber) {

                if (TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE==state){

                rec.stop();
                rec.reset();
                 rec.release();
                    stopSelf();
                }else if(TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK==state && rec==null){

                    try {
                        rec.prepare();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    rec.start();


                }

                }

        },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);

        return START_STICKY;
    }
}
```

ActivityButton1.java

```
package com.example.registrachiamate;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class ActivityButton1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    ToggleButton startandoff;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.button1);
        startandoff=(ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);


    }

   public void tooglebutton(View view)
   {
       boolean checked=((ToggleButton)view).isChecked();
       if (checked){

           Intent intent=new Intent(this,RecordService.class);
           startService(intent);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Call Record STARTED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

       }else {

           Intent intent=new Intent(this,RecordService.class);
           stopService(intent);
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Call Record STOPPED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


   }
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml, if i put the RecordService, in  it stops running

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.registrachiamate">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityButton1"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityButton2"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityButton3"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityButton4"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".RecordService"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```